# directory structure on web server security

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have many directories in a application like

```
root 
index.php
modules/ 
includes/ 
data/
themes/ 
and 
etc.
```

I have placed index html file in every folder to make it simple secure. But i think there must be some better and more secure technique for security.

my question is how can we do it through htacess and php.

Answer (score 3):

Move everything that doesn't *need* to be under the document root out.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you do not need to have all of your files in the publicly accessible part of your server's directory structure. Say you have your document root in:
/applicationname/www/

You can move things that the public doesn't need to see to:

/applicationname/includes/
/applicationname/data/
...etc.

You can still refer to these places in your code (as it uses the server's directory structure), but other people won't be able to access it as its outside your document root.

Answer (score 0):

I would as Andrew, list them as /includes/ or /data/, but putting an index.html will still be a good idea.
Depending on what you use the files for you can use IP-security. $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "your ip" in a simple if, of course if this in some sense should be publicly available this will not be a security.

Comment: i used simple technique. changed index.html to index.php. it contains header('location:/site-name/index.php'). it works...

Comment: But that wouldn't prevent them from accessing /data/secret.php, would it?

Comment: mikkeljuhl, yes you are right ....

Answer (score 0):

```
Options -indexes
```

this will would have the same effect as putting a index.html file in every folder, so people would have to guess the url, instead of getting a nice list of filenames.

To protect the includes folder (and possibly the data as well) you could put a .htaccess file inside in that contains:

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy All
```

This way nobody can access those files from the internet, only PHP can include/read them.